# Android - URI permission is not granted

Tags: android, security

I'm developing two apps that will share some files.
When I run the following intent

```
    Intent next = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.fromFile(new File("/data/data/com.myapp1/shared_prefs/CookiePreferences.xml")));
    next.setClassName("com.myapp2", "com.myapp2.SomeActivity");
    next.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(next);
```

And in the second recipient app this code:

```
        Uri uri = intent.getData();
        grantUriPermission(getPackageName(), uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        InputStream s = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

I get the following exception:

> java.lang.SecurityException: No permission grant found for UID 10242
>   and Uri
>   file:///data/data/com.myapp1/shared_prefs/CookiePreferences.xml

But why? I need to grant this permission exactly via sending intent. What I'm doing wrong? I put a lot of calls like `takePersistableUriPermission` and `grantUriPermission` using advises from the internet, but these calls didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But why?

Because there is no persistable `Uri` permission in this scenario.

> What I'm doing wrong?

First, in your second code snippet, get rid of the `grantUriPermission()` line and the `takePersistableUriPermission()` line, as neither are necessary or will work.

Second, `Uri.fromFile(new File("/data/data/com.myapp1/shared_prefs/CookiePreferences.xml")));` will not work, as the second app does not have access to this file, and `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` is only for `content` `Uri` values.

Third, `SharedPreferences` does not support multiple processes accessing its contents at the same time.

Instead, attach extras to the `Intent` with the data that the second activity needs, and stop trying to use the same `SharedPreferences` in two separate apps.

Comment: No, I'm trying to grant access in the first app, and read data in the second one. `Uri.fromFile` is called in the first one. I'm not trying to use SharedPrefs, I'm just testing files sharing between apps, this file is just a random file I'm playing with

Comment: When I put a `content://` URI, I get the following exception: `java.lang.SecurityException: Requested flags 0x1, but only 0x0 are allowed` (this content provider has `android:grantUriPermissions="true"` btw)

Comment: @Ivan: "I get the following exception" -- I do not recognize that error message, sorry.

Comment: I solved the problem. `file://` uris are not allowed, only `content://` yes. I got the last error, because if I specify `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION` so I should use only `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` in `takePersistableUriPermission` call